# Unable to access static property / field (C#)

Tags: c#, static-members

I am getting a compile time exception that states:

```
Actor.TimeScale.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; 
qualify it with a type name instead.
```

This is the code, which has been cleaned up to just the relevant lines:

```
class Actor
{
    static float _timeScale = 1.0f;

    public static float TimeScale
    {
        get { return _timeScale; }
        set { _timeScale = value; }
    }
}
class Game1
{
    private void BeginLevel()
    {
        Actor.TimeScale = 0.3f;
    }
}
```

Now, I know something is amiss with **static**, but I don't understand what.

Comment: Do you have a property called `Actor` within `Game1` by any chance?

Comment: The code compiles fine for me. Can you post a _complete_ example of your code that reproduces this error?

Comment: Have you any member in `Game1` called `Actor`?

Comment: I'd end up having to upload the whole solution i think. Actor is 130 lines, game1 is 400 lines, but reaches into many other classes.

Comment: No members called actor in game1.

Comment: @sdiguana: Start trimming/commenting away your code until the error resolves itself. Or if it's easier, create a new project with these basic classes and start adding members until it fails. Perhaps also _double_, then _triple_ check the code you posted here compared with the code you actually have: perhaps you typo'd something when posting here that is critical for us to reproduce the error.

Comment: @sdiguana: by any chance, if you replace `Actor.TimeScale = 0.3f;` with `global::Your.Actor.Namespace.Actor.TimeScale = 0.3f;` does the error go away? (be sure to replace "Your.Actor.Namespace" with the namespace that `Actor` resides in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child class of actor had:

```
this.TimeScale;
```

which of course doesnt work so well with static.

Comment: ^ user error on not paying enough attention to which class the debug window was pointing to. (facepalm)